# How do I add a Certificate Authority to PHP so the file() function trusts certificates signed by it?

Tags: php, ssl

I need to open remote resources that are signed by a private company's Certificate Authority. Right now, PHP won't open the resources because it doesn't trust the certificate signer.

I know you can do certificates with the stream context object, but I'm looking for a way to give PHP the public key of a new Certificate Authority and have the `file()` and similar methods trust remote certificates signed by that authority ***without having to create a stream context each time***.

Is there a way to add a new Certificate Authority to php.ini? I tried adding the CA's public key to `/etc/ssl/certs/`, but it doesn't seem to be recognized.

Answer (score 17):

Curl uses a single file with all of the CA's in it. To add a new CA to Curl/PHP, you need to get a complete bundle, add your cert to the bundle, then tell PHP to use the custom bundle.

1. Download the latest bundle from CURL and save it to `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`:

`curl --remote-name --time-cond cacert.pem https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`

2. Edit the `/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` file, and add your new CA public key to the bottom.
3. Edit `php.ini` and add the line `openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem` to the top (or bottom).
4. Restart the webserver.

Comment: The correct address is (now): `curl --remote-name --time-cond cacert.pem https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem`

Comment: to add to this, on Ubuntu php uses the "os-managed certificate store" by default. so you can just put additional files into /etc/ssl/certs. But it seems curl does not use this store but it's own one making things a but confusing and not intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I did it

1- I downloaded the cacert.pem from `https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html`

2- I copied the cert to `/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`

3- I added this line to the php.ini `openssl.cafile= "/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"` and for curl support this line `curl.cainfo = "/usr/local/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"`

4- restart the server and done.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. In some cases, you'll have `cert.pem` instead of `cacert.pem`. Same steps here should work.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out following steps:

Find your `php.ini` with

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

Inside `php.ini` verify/specify path to the certs

```
curl.cainfo =/your/path/cacert.pem
openssl.cafile=/your/path/cacert.pem
```

And the trickiest part:

if you need a **custom certificate** to be added append it to `/your/path/cacert.pem`
It looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I didn't have to restart anything in my case (only php script itself) but I guess it depends